# Autowired value stays null?

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, autowired

In my project (Liferay Portlet), im creating a webservice-client. I've defined a webServiceTemplate in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="be.icredit.einvoice.service, be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest" />


    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.customerdaoservice"/>
    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
         <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" /> 
         <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" /> 
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="http://localhost:8081/ws-demo/account-balance-service" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When i execute testFindCustomer method in my CustomerClient.java, I get a nullpointerexception on the webServiceTemplate.

```
public class CustomerClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

        @Autowired
        private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

        private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomerClient.class);

        public CustomerClient()
        {


        }
        public void testFindCustomer()
        {
            Find findCustomer = new Find();
            findCustomer.setFilter(new CustomerFilter());

            System.out.println(webServiceTemplate.getDefaultUri());
            FindResponse response = (FindResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(findCustomer);

            ArrayList<Customer> list = (ArrayList) response.getReturn();        
            for(Customer c : list)
            {
                log.info("found");
            }

        }
```

This looks pretty basic, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. The CustomerClient class is located in the be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest package.

Nullpointerexceptions happens on the System.out.println(webServiceTemplate.getDefaultUri()); line.

Comment: Do you use already @Autowired in other places? If not, drop <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/> into your XML config.

Comment: Is `CustomerClient` a bean? Annotated with `@Service`?

Comment: CustomerClient is not a bean.

Comment: And I'm allready using the autowired in my controller class. There I have no such problem

Comment: @KornelitoBenito Then you can not use autowiering. This only works in container managed beans.

Comment: Och now I see. I'm very very new at Spring, and learning it 'on the fly' in a project at my new job. Thanks a lot! Those are the little nasty things I forgot :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)